# Py2exe version number for com dll

Tags: python, dll, com, version, py2exe

Is there are a way to add to the dll which py2exe makes a version tag? If I generate a new dll I need to see which function/clases are already implemented and I need to see if there are are already a newer dll that is tagged by a date or a version number (by myself created VN for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use version parameter as in:

```
setup(
    windows = [
              {'script': PyAppName,
               'icon_resources':[(0, Icon)],
               'dest_base' : Exe[:-4],
               'version' : AppVers,
               'company_name' : "JoaquinAbian",
               'copyright' : "No Copyrights",
               'name' : AppName 
              }
              ],
```

where AppVers is your program version

[image]

Comment: I'm using "py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7"

Comment: thanks, but what is really strange, now it generates a new exe which have this information added. But my ddl file still have the same information (no informationen). But if I add to the setup a " version = '1.0' ", attribute it adds this to my ddl file. So finally it works :-)

Comment: @Rolle, I asssumed you were talking about exe files (despite the question title, sorry) because py2exe afaik is not commonly used to prepare dll files. If you are actually creating  a com server dll or similar, you put all these options directly on the setup (see for example [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126379/py2exe-com-dll-problem)) as you already found. There is not much information on dll preparation with py2exe. Maybe you could edit your question and add your code. I will reedit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right there aren't so much informations which I can add but sufficient for me untill now. The documentation on py2exe is also really short. My next step is read this version info with vba but this is off topic.