# python py2exe: exe creation/errors

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, py2exe

I'm trying to create a windows executable for a python program using tkinter. This is essentially a webscraper using the requests module. I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting my issue. I'm able to create the exe and run it. My program has a login view, and when this is submitted and requests are made is when the error shows up. You need to be using a VPN to make these requests, so I'm not posting all my code here yet. Please let me know if any additional info/code is needed. The following error only shows up when running the exe, not the original python file. Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1486, in __call__
  File "Dest_gui.py", line 222, in login_gui
  File "Dest_gui.py", line 29, in login
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 498, in post
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 456, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 559, in send
  File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 382, in send
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 certificate      routines
:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136255/requests-lib-and-py2exe-com-server-issue?rq=1) might be a related issue, looks like this person thought the conflict was with py2exe and requests, but it wasn't resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this working with py2exe, but it does work just fine using [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki). You just need to have [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) installed also.